# Какие есть способы преобразовать строку в список?

Tags: python

У меня есть строка:

```
'[1 , 2, 3, 4]'
```

как я могу преобразовать ее в список?

```
arr=[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: А откуда строка?

Comment: я получаю строку из текстового файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал через `ast.literal_eval`

Пример:

```
import ast

text = '[1 , 2, 3, 4]'
items = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(type(items), items)
# <class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно десериализовать с помощью модуля `json`.

```
import json

s = '[1 , 2, 3, 4]'
arr = json.loads(s)
```

Так как эта запись массива полностью совместима с форматом json'а, то проблем не возникнет. И это намного безопаснее и эффективнее, чем использовать eval или парсить самому.

Answer (score 0):

или можно попробовать через регулярку:

```
from re import findall
arr = [int(i) for i in findall(r'\d+',text)]
```

Comment: У вас каждую отдельную цифру будет считать за отдельное число (например, 12 превратится в два числа - 1 и 2). Как минимум нужно + в регулярке добавить, чтобы соседние цифры матчились вместе: `r'\d+'`.

Comment: согласен. упустил это. код подправил.